# I have a code part where I use switch statement for defining the behaivours case by case. Is it possible to write this code without switch statement?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a c# app where I have to show elements of the correct list regarding the selection of the user. There are several lists and related to the selection of the user I have show the correct list on the screen.

Additionally I have to make some other process on list, regarding the selection.

I have used a switch statement for selecting the correct list but, because there are a lot of cases the code gets longer and longer. How can I shorten my code without using a switch stement? Or when switch is needed: Is it possible to use the case part in a for loop to shorten it?

```
public void Split_List()
{
switch (TagService.NC_GUD_selected_type[index_])
        {

            case "SGUD": 
                for (int m = 0; m < SGUD_List_from_TreeWriter.LongCount(); m++)
                {
                    Split_GUD_attr = SGUD_List_from_TreeWriter[m].Split(";");
                    k = m;
                }
                break;
            case "MGUD":
                for (int m = 0; m < MGUD_List_from_TreeWriter.LongCount(); m++)
                {
                    Split_GUD_attr = MGUD_List_from_TreeWriter[m].Split(";");
                    k = m;
                }
                break;
            case "UGUD":
                for (int m = 0; m < UGUD_List_from_TreeWriter.LongCount(); m++)
                {
                    Split_GUD_attr = UGUD_List_from_TreeWriter[m].Split(";");
                    k = m;
                }
                break;
            case "GUD4":
                for (int m = 0; m < GUD4_List_from_TreeWriter.LongCount(); m++)
                {
                    Split_GUD_attr = GUD4_List_from_TreeWriter[m].Split(";");
                    k = m;
                }
                break;
            case "GUD5":
                for (int m = 0; m < GUD5_List_from_TreeWriter.LongCount(); m++)
                {
                    Split_GUD_attr = GUD5_List_from_TreeWriter[m].Split(";");
                    k = m;
                }
                break;
            case "GUD6":
                for (int m = 0; m < GUD6_List_from_TreeWriter.LongCount(); m++)
                {
                    Split_GUD_attr = GUD6_List_from_TreeWriter[m].Split(";");
                    k = m;
                }
                break;
            case "GUD7":
                for (int m = 0; m < GUD7_List_from_TreeWriter.LongCount(); m++)
                {
                    Split_GUD_attr = GUD7_List_from_TreeWriter[m].Split(";");
                    k = m;
                }
                break;
            case "GUD8":
                for (int m = 0; m < GUD8_List_from_TreeWriter.LongCount(); m++)
                {
                    Split_GUD_attr = GUD8_List_from_TreeWriter[m].Split(";");
                    k = m;
                }
                break;
            case "GUD9":
                for (int m = 0; m < GUD9_List_from_TreeWriter.LongCount(); m++)
                {
                    Split_GUD_attr = GUD9_List_from_TreeWriter[m].Split(";");
                    k = m;
                }
                break;

                // possible other cases
        }

        GUD_List_to_screen = Split_GUD_attr[0] + Split_GUD_attr[6] + "  (" + Split_GUD_attr[1] + ")";
        CNC_GUD_Out_Array_total[index_, k] = GUD_List_to_screen;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To shorten your code, you can create a dictionary that maps each selection to its corresponding list.

```cs
public void Split_List()
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> listDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
    {
        { "SGUD", SGUD_List_from_TreeWriter },
        { "MGUD", MGUD_List_from_TreeWriter },
        { "UGUD", UGUD_List_from_TreeWriter },
        { "GUD4", GUD4_List_from_TreeWriter },
        { "GUD5", GUD5_List_from_TreeWriter },
        { "GUD6", GUD6_List_from_TreeWriter },
        { "GUD7", GUD7_List_from_TreeWriter },
        { "GUD8", GUD8_List_from_TreeWriter },
        { "GUD9", GUD9_List_from_TreeWriter }
        // Add other cases here
    };

    if (listDictionary.TryGetValue(TagService.NC_GUD_selected_type[index_], out List<string> selectedList))
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < selectedList.Count; m++)
        {
            Split_GUD_attr = selectedList[m].Split(";");
            k = m;

            GUD_List_to_screen = Split_GUD_attr[0] + Split_GUD_attr[6] + "  (" + Split_GUD_attr[1] + ")";
            CNC_GUD_Out_Array_total[index_, k] = GUD_List_to_screen;
        }
    }
}
```

To add new cases, you can simply extend the dictionary with the new selection and its associated list.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Have learnt something new today. Thank you so much!!!